# Devotion to God and Vegetarianism

Tags: vishnu, non-vegetarian, garuda

We are often taught that non-vegetarians will go to Hell and it's being condemned by the scriptures and numerous Gurus. And so it implies that a devotee of God never eats meat or else he/she will not attain liberation.
But Garuda is often described as eating snakes and fishes. And he is one of the most ardent devotees of Lord Visnu to the point of him being appointed by the Lord to be his carrier. 
How is this possible? Doesn't it contradict the shastras?

Comment: It doesn't. In Vedic era, Kshatriya and Sudras used to eat meat. Can we imagine a Sattvik person killing other people? No, right? That is why Rajas and Tamas has to be there in certain ratio to enable Kshatriya and Sudras to do their respective works. Eating meat used to help them in their respective work i.e. Kshatriya to rule and kill in battle and Sudras to do hard work in Agriculture or giving service.